# Command prompt failed to execute command with syntax-FOR-Command Results

Tags: windows, cmd, command-line, dos

In one of my Windows device, it failed to execute the command with syntax-FOR-Command Results

```
FOR /f %I IN ('dir') DO ECHO %I
```

Already tried to edit the regedit by deleting all values under

> Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor

And edit the PATH parameter remain with

> C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\system32

But still return same result.
The "dir" command can execute successfully when it is not used for the Command Result.

The version of the command prompt

> Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.2486]
> (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Command prompt Result

[image: 1]

I tried on some other device and it success to return expected result by the 'dir' command result.

Comment: You need to stop doing destructive things to your PC. Please restore all of the regustry data back to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor`. Then put back the rest of the locations in your system environment PATH. If you"ve been messing with other things you shouldn't have, and you do not have a restore point from a date before then, you may even have to consider reinstalling your OS.

Comment: @Compo Thanks for the comment, I've already backup the keys and setting before I edited them and already restore the setting. I think I may not able to reinstall the OS since the device belongs to the company. Besides, would I able to reinstall the cmd and related components only?

Comment: You must replace the registry information and at least have the Windows defaults in your environment variables. Once you've done that, [Edit] your question to show us those settings

Comment: What becomes displayed when you do `echo %ComSpec%`?

Comment: @aschipfl It returns "C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe"